# Regular expression to filter links

Tags: php, regex

I am using this regular expression to filter .pdffiles from the webpage:

```
    $regex='|<a.*?href="(.*pdf?)"|';
```

It does the job if the link is like this:

```
 www.xyz.com/trgrrtr/ghtty.pdf
```

but if the links are something like this, it is unable to filter:

```
 www.xyz.com/trgrrtr/ghtty.pdf?code=KksRHhdVXAoECBFCVFpeXBsBUgYMDQpxd3J2d3F2fDtzfnFuLiErNXNpIG5kYm16aGhpcmxoa05QV1VKUVFFUxQ%3D
```

What regular expression I should use to filter out this link from a webpage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you need to escape the `?` otherwise it just makes the `f` in front of it optional. Then you could do something like this:

```
$regex = '|<a.*?href="([^"]*\.pdf\?[^"]*)"|';
```

The use of the negated character class makes sure that you cannot leave the attribute. (`.*` could consume the attribute-ending `"` as well, and go on until `"` matches another double quote further down the string.)

But I really recommend that you use a DOM parser to find the link-elements first. PHP has a [built-in one](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) and there is a very nice and convenient [3rd-party alternative](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net).

Comment: @m-buettner your code is deleting the domain name . for example it shows only  /fjfrkr/fgfj.pdf not the domain name

Comment: @PayalMalhotra sorry, but I cannot reproduce this. Could you show the relevant part of your input string, please?

Comment: @PayalMalhotra that seems all right, but I really meant your **input string** and not your code ;)

Comment: @m-buettner http://cvcc.sdddem.com/ddsd/Idddno/K/ddddfd/Asdsku_sds_Kamu.pdf?code=KksRHhdVXAoECBFCVFpeXBsBUgYMDQpxd3NycXJwfDtzfnFuLiErNXNpIG5kZW16aGhpcmxpa05UUU1TUURcFQ%3D%3D

Comment: @PayalMalhotra please surround the link with this character: `\``

Comment: can u plz modify the code . i tried but output is coming nothing just blank page

Comment: @PayalMalhotra, please just edit your question and add some example input (what is `$result21`?). Then let me know in a comment, so I can have a look.

Comment: @PayalMalhotra once again. Please **edit your question** and show some **example input** (i.e. the **content** of `$result21` and not how you have retrieved).

Comment: websitelink is the link of website from which i am trying to extract the links and result21 is output of all links from websitelink page aftere that i am perforning check and echoing only result which matches the criterion

Comment: @PayalMalhotra are you even reading my comments? It does not help me at all to know where you get that data from. Just **edit**. **your**. **question**. with the value of `$result21`.

Answer (score 0):

The blog post *[An Improved Liberal, Accurate Regex Pattern for Matching URLs](http://daringfireball.net/2010/07/improved_regex_for_matching_urls)* may help.